# Refreshing ListFragment data

Tags: android

Im using supportApi for lower versions. I have a listFragment and an asynchAdapter which loads data in background from web. The problem is if the data is changed in Background I cant make the listFragment to refresh and show the new data. I have a customListAdapter that extend baseAdapter and I am calling setlistadapter(customListAdapter) in my ListFragment. I need some example which implements something like this not the cursorAdapter or simpleArrayAdapter.

The only problem I have is I dont know how to refresh the listFragment as onResume doesnt gets called and not sure if notifydatasetchange will work on listfragment. Some pieces of my code is as follow.

the onLoadFinish gets call only once when I initialize loader. The onresume gets called only once as well. May be my approach is wrong but that what I am not sure about.

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<MyData>> {

    private ArrayList<MyData> mydata;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), mydata);

        setListAdapter(this.adapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<MyData>> Loader, ArrayList<MyData> mydata) {
        this.adapter.setData(mydata);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the notifyDatasetChange and it works for me.